# pagination codeigniter always starts at page 2 and active link is always at page 2

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

i'm new to codeigniter and i'm using codeigniter pagination by getting query result from Category Id, but the page always starts at page 2 .
how do i fix the pagination to set the start page at number page 1?

```
public function kategori($kat=''){

$config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/lowongan/kategori/'.$kat;
$data['db']=$this->query->katPostingan($kat);       
$config['total_rows'] = $data['db']->num_rows(); 
$config['per_page'] = 1;    
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$data2['paging'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

$page = ($this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment'])) ? $this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment']) : 0;
$data2['records'] = $this->query->katPos($kat, $config['per_page'], $page);

$this->load->view( 'user/hal_kategori',$data2);
    }
```

and my model

```
public function katPos($kat='',$limit,$start){
$this->db->where("id_kat", $kat);
$this->db->limit($limit,$start);
    $query = $this->db->get("showKat");
    return $query;
}

    public function katPostingan($kat=''){
            $this->db->where("id_kat", $kat);
            $query = $this->db->get("showKat");
        return $query;
    }
```

Comment: whats the initial value of $kat passing to kategori

Comment: the initial value of $kat is category id from category so if the url http://localhost/kp/index.php/lowongan/kategori/0001, then $kat value is 0001

Answer (score 0):

try a different way of solution,

controller(index())

```
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = site_url().'classname/index';
        $config['per_page'] = $this->config->item('pagination_number');
        $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
        $data['count']=$this->example_model->count();
        $config['total_rows'] =$data['count'];
        $data['classname']=$this->example_model->getall($this->config->item('pagination_number'),$this->uri->segment(4));
        $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
        $data['page_link']=$this->pagination->create_links();


        $this->load->view('users/classname.php',$data);
```

model

```
function getall($num,$offset)
{
    $this->db->from('table_name');
    $this->db->limit($num,$offset);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
function count()
{
    $this->db->from('table_name');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $rowcount = $query->num_rows();
    return( $rowcount);
}
```

View

```
<div class="pagination"> <?php echo $page_link;?> </div>
```